# My reverse-ssh tunnel is using keepalives but they're not helping

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, sshd

I have an ssh client machine **picard** behind multiple unreliable internet connections - all with NAT.

I have my server **time**, reliable with a static IP. I want to be able to access **picard** thorugh **time**. I've done this before:

```
$ ssh -N -R 19999:localhost:22 user@my.domain
```

This works, but if there is a problem it exits and does not restart, and it doesn't start on boot, so now I add a systemd service to run:

```
/bin/bash -c "while true; do /usr/bin/ssh -i <unencrypted key> \
  -o ServerAliveInterval=10 -v -o ServerAliveCountMax=6 -N \
    -R 19999:localhost:22 user@my.domain; sleep 5; done"`

while true ... sleep 5    # re-runs ssh if it exits
```

- `-o ServerAliveInterval=10` sends a keep-alive every 10 seconds
- `-o ServerAliveCountMax=6` exits if 6 keep-alives go out with no response
- `-v` keeps debug info in `/var/log/messages` through systemd

On the server side I added a couple of lines to `sshd_config`:

```
KeepAlive yes
ClientAliveInterval 10
ClientAliveCountMax 6
```

Same idea as the client -  break the connection after 60s of inactivity.

Unfortunately it seems to take a lot longer than a minute to restart:

```
< tunnel is up and keepalives are coming in >
Jun  7 17:31:02 picard bash[135]: debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype keepalive@openssh.com want_reply 1
Jun  7 17:31:12 picard bash[135]: debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype keepalive@openssh.com want_reply 1
Jun  7 17:31:15 picard bash[135]: debug1: client_input_channel_open: ctype forwarded-tcpip rchan 2 win 2097152 max 32768
Jun  7 17:31:15 picard bash[135]: debug1: client_request_forwarded_tcpip: listen localhost port 19998, originator 127.0.0.1 port 38267
Jun  7 17:31:15 picard bash[135]: debug1: connect_next: host localhost ([127.0.0.1]:22) in progress, fd=4
Jun  7 17:31:15 picard bash[135]: debug1: channel 0: new [127.0.0.1]
Jun  7 17:31:15 picard bash[135]: debug1: confirm forwarded-tcpip
Jun  7 17:31:15 picard bash[135]: debug1: channel 0: connected to localhost port 22
Jun  7 17:31:20 picard systemd-logind[137]: New session 1 of user main_username.
< I break eth0 and plug it back in after NM sees it's down >
< eth0 is back up within a few seconds >
< nothing happens with my ssh connection for a LONG time >
Jun  7 17:54:16 picard bash[135]: Write failed: Broken pipe
Jun  7 17:54:22 picard bash[135]: OpenSSH_6.1p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1c-fips 10 May 2012
Jun  7 17:54:22 picard bash[135]: debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
Jun  7 17:54:22 picard bash[135]: debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 50: Applying options for *
Jun  7 17:54:22 picard bash[135]: debug1: Connecting to my.domain [123.234.123.234] port 22.
Jun  7 17:54:22 picard bash[135]: debug1: Connection established.
Jun  7 17:54:23 picard bash[135]: debug1: identity file /home/test/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
Jun  7 17:54:23 picard bash[135]: debug1: identity file /home/test/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
Jun  7 17:54:23 picard bash[135]: debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-1ubuntu3
Jun  7 17:54:23 picard bash[135]: debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-1ubuntu3 pat OpenSSH_5*
Jun  7 17:54:23 picard bash[135]: debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
Jun  7 17:54:23 picard bash[135]: debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.1
Jun  7 17:54:23 picard bash[135]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
Jun  7 17:54:23 picard bash[135]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
Jun  7 17:54:23 picard bash[135]: debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
Jun  7 17:54:23 picard bash[135]: debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
Jun  7 17:54:23 picard bash[135]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
Jun  7 17:54:23 picard bash[135]: debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
Jun  7 17:54:23 picard bash[135]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
Jun  7 17:54:23 picard bash[135]: debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
Jun  7 17:54:23 picard bash[135]: debug1: Server host key: RSA 7a:19:72:9d:f5:39:f5:03:cf:16:b2:ee:fc:a4:e6:ba
Jun  7 17:54:23 picard bash[135]: debug1: Host 'my.domain' is known and matches the RSA host key.
Jun  7 17:54:23 picard bash[135]: debug1: Found key in /home/test/.ssh/known_hosts:1
Jun  7 17:54:23 picard bash[135]: debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
Jun  7 17:54:23 picard bash[135]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
Jun  7 17:54:23 picard bash[135]: debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
Jun  7 17:54:23 picard bash[135]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
Jun  7 17:54:23 picard bash[135]: debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
Jun  7 17:54:23 picard bash[135]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
Jun  7 17:54:23 picard bash[135]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
Jun  7 17:54:23 picard bash[135]: debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Jun  7 17:54:23 picard bash[135]: debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
Jun  7 17:54:23 picard bash[135]: debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/test/.ssh/id_rsa
Jun  7 17:54:23 picard bash[135]: debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
Jun  7 17:54:23 picard bash[135]: debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
Jun  7 17:54:24 picard bash[135]: debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Jun  7 17:54:24 picard bash[135]: Authenticated to my.domain ([123.234.123.234]:22).
Jun  7 17:54:24 picard bash[135]: debug1: Remote connections from LOCALHOST:19999 forwarded to local address localhost:22
Jun  7 17:54:24 picard bash[135]: debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
Jun  7 17:54:24 picard bash[135]: debug1: Entering interactive session.
Jun  7 17:54:24 picard bash[135]: debug1: remote forward success for: listen 19999, connect localhost:22
Jun  7 17:54:24 picard bash[135]: debug1: All remote forwarding requests processed
Jun  7 17:54:44 picard bash[135]: debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype keepalive@openssh.com want_reply 1
Jun  7 17:54:45 picard bash[135]: debug1: client_input_channel_open: ctype forwarded-tcpip rchan 2 win 2097152 max 32768
Jun  7 17:54:45 picard bash[135]: debug1: client_request_forwarded_tcpip: listen localhost port 19999, originator 127.0.0.1 port 60222
Jun  7 17:54:45 picard bash[135]: debug1: connect_next: host localhost ([127.0.0.1]:22) in progress, fd=4
Jun  7 17:54:45 picard bash[135]: debug1: channel 0: new [127.0.0.1]
Jun  7 17:54:45 picard bash[135]: debug1: confirm forwarded-tcpip
Jun  7 17:54:45 picard bash[135]: debug1: channel 0: connected to localhost port 22
Jun  7 17:54:50 picard systemd-logind[137]: New session 3 of user main_username.
< whenever I connect the keepalive debug messages stop coming, not sure if this is normal >
```

I'm sure I've overlooked something. I've seen some projects like `autossh` that do pretty much the same thing I'm doing now, but I'd like to be able to fix this if possible. How do I get the delay down to 2-3 minutes instead of 23 minutes?

Comment: Maybe SSH is unable to rebind the port immediately? 23 minutes seem exagerated though...

Answer (score 4):

What if you used a tool like `autossh` to maintain your ssh connections instead? I use [autossh](http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/index.html) to maintain both an smtp (port 25) and imap (port 143) open on my laptop back through a server on the internet with multiple servers behind it that are accessing the internet via NAT.

```
                                                              smtp (25)
                                                               __  _   
                                                              [__]|=|  
                                                              /::/|_|  
 laptop          .-,(  ),-.         Ext. Host      Int. Host      ^
  (22)        .-(          )-.         (22)           (22)        |
  __  _ ---->(    internet    )----> __  _   -----> __  _   ------.
 [__]|=|      '-(          ).-'     [__]|=|        [__]|=|        |
 /::/|_|          '-.( ).-'         /::/|_|        /::/|_|        v
                                                             imap (143)
                                                              __  _    
                                                             [__]|=|   
                                                             /::/|_|
```

With the above setup I use the following `autossh` command to set it up on my laptop:

```
autossh -M 0 -f -N -L 2025:localhost:25 -L 2143:localhost:143 me@int-host
```

In my `$HOME/.ssh/config` file I've setup a host rule like so:

```
Host int-host
    ProxyCommand ssh me@ext-host nc int-host %p
```

Comment: Thanks, like I mentioned - I saw `autossh` and might end up using it, but my question is about the keepalive option in ssh/sshd and why it's not behaving the way I expect.

Comment: Understand but I've not had good luck with your approach either and was showing you something that has worked.